# Change the install directory, npm with package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package, package.json

I have a package.json that looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\""
  }  ,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to install bootstrap in another directory than "node_modues". If so, how to I write that in the "package.json" file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in `package.json`:

```
{
 "scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install bootstrap --prefix ./another/"
 }
}
```

your module will be installed in ./another/node_module

**NOTE**: So you can use another options in this scripts for installing modules as you want.